# Why windows 10 won't install?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, installation, updates

I just got an notification that win10 is available and downloaded it. Everything went fine and at last when probably at 48%, (installing drivers and features), it just rebooted and told that restoring your previous version of windows. It restored and a popup told that error code is 80070004-3000D. What to do now? Please help.
Now, it shows that my copy of windows is not genuine..
Huh.. Please help..

Edit: I'm using Asus x200ma. I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to my BIOS. Because I have an option in my BIOS to choose OS (Win7 or win8.1). Should I try using the option. As after selection win8.x, win 7 won't work. Please help. My OS is windows7 ultimate x32. Please help. And also, I can't use media creation tool or ISO image. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue recently as well as I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 Ultimate. You will have to do a clean installation of 10 through the BIOS and boot to a removable media (USB or disc). Make sure you have your product key handy. You can go to Microsoft's website and use the updater there to make a removable media OS update. Its about 3 GB.

Comment: I can't as my machine Asus x200ma doesn't support USB for installation. I have the iso file but hard luck.

Comment: OK, I'm going to Microsoft and post this as an question. Looks like the experts here can't do anything with my problem! :(